# Redirecting after Submit button in PHP not working

Tags: php, redirect, form-submit

Trying to redirect to another page if all queries are inserted in the database, but it is not redirecting instead showing a warning and not redirecting it.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp64\www\quiz\quiz.php:183) in C:\wamp64\www\quiz\quiz.php on line 249

***My Codes*: (The code are started from the line: `180` till the EOF)**

```
    <h1><?php echo $it; ?>)&nbsp;<?php echo $Question; ?></h1></br>
    <input type="hidden" name="tqid<?php echo $iii; ?>" value="<?php echo $QRN ?>">
    <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="tradio<?php echo $iii; ?>" value="T">&nbsp;&nbsp;True</h2>
    <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="tradio<?php echo $iii; ?>" value="F">&nbsp;&nbsp;False</h2>
    </div>
    <hr></br></br>
    <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn-submit">Submit</button>
</form>

    <script src="<?php echo $web; ?>vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $web; ?>bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><script src="<?php echo $users; ?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
}
$asth = $user->runQuery("SELECT MAX(Sr) as Sr FROM answer");
$asth->execute();
$aresult = $asth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$atf= ($aresult['Sr']);
$aI = "1";
$acid = $atf + $aI;
$arn = $fddate.$ydate.$mdate.$frandno.$acid;
$count = $i;
for($j = 1; $j <= $count; $j++)
{ 
if(isset($_POST['btn-submit'])) {
$ufname = trim($_POST['radio'.$j]);
$Qrn = trim($_POST['qid'.$j]); 
$istmt = $user->runQuery("INSERT INTO answer(ARN,Ans,QRN,SRN) VALUES(:user_arn, :user_crn, :user_qrn, :user_srn)");
$istmt->bindparam(":user_qrn",$Qrn);
$istmt->bindparam(":user_crn",$ufname);
$istmt->bindparam(":user_arn",$arn);
$istmt->bindparam(":user_srn",$srn);
$istmt->execute();  
}
}
$fcount = $ii;
for($fj = 1; $fj <= $fcount; $fj++)
{ 
if(isset($_POST['btn-submit'])) {
$fufname = trim($_POST['fans'.$fj]);
$fQrn = trim($_POST['fqid'.$fj]); 
$fistmt = $user->runQuery("INSERT INTO answer(ARN,Ans,QRN,SRN) VALUES(:user_arn, :user_fcrn, :user_fqrn, :user_srn)");
$fistmt->bindparam(":user_fqrn",$fQrn);
$fistmt->bindparam(":user_fcrn",$fufname);
$fistmt->bindparam(":user_arn",$arn);
$fistmt->bindparam(":user_srn",$srn);
$fistmt->execute(); 
}
}
$tcount = $iii;
for($tj = 1; $tj <= $tcount; $tj++)
{ 
if(isset($_POST['btn-submit'])) {
$tufname = trim($_POST['tradio'.$tj]);
$tQrn = trim($_POST['tqid'.$tj]); 
$tistmt = $user->runQuery("INSERT INTO answer(ARN,Ans,QRN,SRN) VALUES(:user_arn, :user_tcrn, :user_tqrn, :user_srn)");
$tistmt->bindparam(":user_tqrn",$tQrn);
$tistmt->bindparam(":user_tcrn",$tufname);
$tistmt->bindparam(":user_arn",$arn);
$tistmt->bindparam(":user_srn",$srn);
$tistmt->execute(); 
$locationei = "result.php";
$locatione = $web.$locationei;
//$user->redirect($locatione);
header("Location: $locatione");
}
}
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: The hint is already in Warning : "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp64\www\quiz\quiz.php:183) in C:\wamp64\www\quiz\quiz.php on line 249 " . Some thing has already sent to browser from quiz.php ;D .Now your header('Location:url') wont work as expected

Comment: @Shan Is this because of: `if(empty($_GET['student']))
{
  $user->redirect($newst);
}` ?

Comment: @KirkBeard The link didn't help me...

Answer (score 0):

Move the PHP code to the top of the page and add `exit()` after the header redirect statement.

All HTML code goes after all PHP code not before.

Comment: If I put `PHP` before `HTML` there is notice. `Notice: Undefined variable: i in C:\wamp64\www\quiz\quiz.php on line 54`

Comment: All logic has to come before the HTML template. It's that simple. There is no way around it. You have to rearrange your code to resolve dependencies and check for undefined values.

Comment: Some `PHP` portion is on top, some middle and some at the end.